# Adding a letter to the end of a variable name

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has these variable names: `"X_1","X_106","X_110","X_111","X_112"`  as well as other names that start with other letters of the alphabet. I am interested in appending `"_v1"` only to variables that start with `"X"` as shown above. How do I accomplish this in R?

Answer (score 5):

or just:

```
colnames(dat) <- sub("(^X.*)", "\\1_v1", colnames(dat))
```

ex:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=1, b=2, c=3,
                  X_1=4, X_106=5, X_110=6, X_111=7, X_112=8)

dplyr::glimpse(dat)
## Observations: 1
## Variables: 8
## $ a     (dbl) 1
## $ b     (dbl) 2
## $ c     (dbl) 3
## $ X_1   (dbl) 4
## $ X_106 (dbl) 5
## $ X_110 (dbl) 6
## $ X_111 (dbl) 7
## $ X_112 (dbl) 8

colnames(dat) <- sub("(^X.*)", "\\1_v1", colnames(dat))

dplyr::glimpse(dat)
## Observations: 1
## Variables: 8
## $ a        (dbl) 1
## $ b        (dbl) 2
## $ c        (dbl) 3
## $ X_1_v1   (dbl) 4
## $ X_106_v1 (dbl) 5
## $ X_110_v1 (dbl) 6
## $ X_111_v1 (dbl) 7
## $ X_112_v1 (dbl) 8
```

Comment: You could just do `str(dat)` instead of loading a package and typing so much, just saying. Nice solution otherwise.

Comment: I really prefer the `glimpse` output over `str`

Comment: They only differ by `num` vs `(dbl)` or am I missing something?

Comment: try it on `mtcars` and `iris`. you usually get more data points (useless here, i realize) more compactly esp w/factors. it's also a snippet in RStudio for me so practically no typing.

Comment: When you are running this on `iris`, you don't know how many factors there are in the `Species` column, isn't this a major draw back? For instance, if you are running some statistical analysis you may not notice that you have a variable with only one level in the data.

Comment: Thanks guys for your responses

Answer (score 3):

```
names(df2) <- ifelse(grepl("^X",names(df2)), paste0(names(df2),"_v1"), names(df2))
```

Comment: Or `g <- grepl("^X",names(df2)); names(df2)[g] <- paste0(names(df2)[g],"_v1")` to drop the `ifelse()` call

Comment: @RichardScriven And hey, why not `library(data.table); setDT(list(names(dat)))[grep("^X",V1), V1 := paste0(V1,"_v1")]`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be as simple as:

```
library(stringr)
names(my_data) <- ifelse(str_detect(names(my_data), "^X_"), paste(names(my_data), "v1", sep = "_"), names(my_data))
```

The `str_detect(names(my_data), "^X_")` is what looks for names that start with an X_.